# Edit docx, pptx, xlsx files in iOS Sdk

Tags: ios, openxml

He All,

I want to edit docx, xlsx and pptx files on iPad. I have done so many research on this. I have found one formate called "OOXML" formate  which which is responsible for the same.

[Ecma-376 standards](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm)

They have mentioned the ebooks for understanding the OOXML format. It is useful resource.

But my Problem is how I can manage to do the same in the iOS as there are so many apps are on the appStore which are manage to do the same. So there is a way by which we can edit dock,pptx,xlxs and save them on the iOs.

Can any one have idea or some reference or library which is able to do the same.

I have also seen the libopc library.

[libopc documentation](http://libopc.codeplex.com/documentation)

Thanks.

Comment: Just use libopc, the link at the bottom. That's the one that everyone uses for iOS. There's a demo video on that CodePlex site. You will need to understand the OOXML format in much more detail in order to do editing, but start from the link on Ecma 376 that you also posted. Note that libopc is just an OPC tool, you'll need edit the XML in your own code.

Comment: @ToddMain Thanks for explaining the stuff. I also need to edit MS office files in my iOS app. Can you guide us more through this.